# Joins in eloquent orm Php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a form in which user have to select from one table to last one i.e

```
buisnessarea->katogorie->name->genauer->geometrie->ergebnisse
```

I have a database something like this.

```
buisnessarea
**buisnessarea_katogorie(pivot table for buisnessarea and katogorie )**
katogorie
**katogorie_name(pivot table for katogorie and name )**
name
**genauer_name(pivot table for name and genauer)**
genauer
**genauer_geometrie(pivot table for genauer and geometrie )**
geometrie
ergebnisse(foreign keys for name and geometrie)
```

now i want to join all of these tables.The purpose for this is.I want to get the buisnessarea in terms of geometrie.
e.g if i got the geometrie id of 10.So i want to get the buisnessrea which lead to the geometrie id of 10.

**Models**

**Buisnessarea**

```
public function katogorie()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Katogorie')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Katogorie**

```
public function buisnessarea()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Buisnessarea')->withTimestamps();
    }

     public function name()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Name');
    }
```

**Name**

```
public function katogorie()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Katogorie');
    }
     public function genauer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Genauer');
    }

    public function ergebnisse()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ergebnisse');
    }
```

**Genauer**

```
public function name()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Name');
    }

    public function geometrie()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Geometrie');
    }
```

**Geometrie**

```
public function genauer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Genauer');
    }

     public function ergebnisse()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ergebnisse');
    }

    public function stufen()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Stufen');
    }
```

**Ergebnisse**

```
public function name()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Name');
    }

    public function geometrie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Geometrie');
    }

    public function katogorie()
    {
         return $this->hasManyThrough('Katogorie','Name',)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry.My Mistake.. Models are now added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Laravel 5 you can do something along the lines of this:

```
$geometrie = Geometrie::with("genauer.name.katogorie.buisnessarea")->find($id);

$buisnessareaOfGeometrie = data_get($geometrie, "genauer.name.katogorie.buisnessarea");
```

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when i dd($buisnessareaOfGeometrie); its returning null

Comment: If you're sure there should be data there then I suggest going one step at a time (doing `Geometrie::find($id)` then `Geometrie::with("genauer")->find($id)`) and checking at each step that the relationship is loaded as expected.

Comment: Geometrie::with("genauer")->find($id)).geometrie and genauer have many to many relationship so they are already working.My problem is e.g geometrie and name or geometrie and buisnessarea dont have direct relation between them so how can i get data then..

Comment: Read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading specifically **Nested Eager Loading**